# Need help deleting/removing kivy widgets

Tags: python, kivy

The code below makes an app with a big button which makes and appends individual "rows" of widgets (really just 3 labels and a button in a  single gridlayout, representing a single widget)
to the bottom of a scrollview.

I want some way to press the 'delete this' button in a row to delete that particular row.
I imagine I'd need some way to differentiate between these generated rows somehow but I haven't gotten that figured out yet either.
I'd be extatic if someone had an elegant solution for this, as I've been stuck here for quite some time.

[screenshot of dummy program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdMx1.png)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kv = '''
<Label>:
    font_size: 35

<delete_btn>:
    background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    text: 'Delete this'
    font_size: 25

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        size_hint: 1, .25
        font_size: 50
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}
        text: 'append row'
        on_press: rootgrid.append_row()

    ScrollviewLayout:
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_width: 10
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .2}

        RootGridLayout:
            id: rootgrid
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

'''

class GridRow(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GridRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None

        self.cols = 4
        self.add_widget(delete_btn())
        self.add_widget(Label(text='00:00:00', size_hint_y=None))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='00:00:00', size_hint_y=None))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='00:00:00', size_hint_y=None))


class RootGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def append_row(self):
        self.add_widget(GridRow())

class delete_btn(Button):
    pass

class ScrollviewLayout(ScrollView):
    pass

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class remtimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_string(kv)
    remtimeApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is important that the setup of a `GridRow` happens in Python but if not you can also solve your problem inside the KV language. You only need to change the code for the GridRow class:

```
<Label>:
    font_size: 35

<GridRow>:
    id: row
    cols: 4
    size_hint_y: None
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        text: '00:00:00'
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        text: '00:00:00'
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        text: '00:00:00'
    Button:
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint_y: None
        text: 'Delete this'
        font_size: 25
        on_press: row.parent.remove_widget(row)

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        size_hint: 1, .25
        font_size: 50
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}
        text: 'append row'
        on_press: rootgrid.append_row()

    ScrollviewLayout:
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_width: 10
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .2}

        RootGridLayout:
            id: rootgrid
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
```

With this the `delete_btn` class and the `GridRow.__init__` function are not needed anymore.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Thankyou! This was a great thing to wake up to today, haha. I marked this the most elegant solution.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but what does the ".parent" in `row.parent.remove_widget(row)` do?

Comment: Sorry to answer so late. See [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.parent). It is a reference to the parent of `row` so whatever container `row` is in. In this case this is the one `RootGridLayout` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the information needed for the deletion when you create the `GridRow` and the `delete_btn`. Here are the affected classes with the changes:

```
class GridRow(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.container = kwargs.pop('container', None)
        super(GridRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None

        self.cols = 4
        self.add_widget(delete_btn(row=self, container=self.container))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='00:00:00', size_hint_y=None))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='00:00:00', size_hint_y=None))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='00:00:00', size_hint_y=None))


class RootGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def append_row(self):
        self.add_widget(GridRow(container=self))


class delete_btn(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.container = kwargs.pop('container', None)
        self.row = kwargs.pop('row', None)
        super(delete_btn, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_release(self):
        self.container.remove_widget(self.row)
```

So the `GridRow` `__init__()` method now takes a keyword parameter of `container`, which should be the `RootGridLayout` that contains the `GridRows`. And the `delete_btn` `__init__()` method takes two keyword arguments, `container` (just passed along from the `GridRow`) and `row`, which is the `GridRow` instance containing the `delete_btn`. That provide the `delete_btn` with all the information necessary to remove its `GridRow` from the `RootGridLayout`. Now the `on_release()` method of the `delete_btn` just does the `remove_widget()`.

Comment: You're an angel for not just helping me, but teaching me as well! THANKYOU!!!

Comment: For `self.container.remove_widget(self.row)` to work `self.row` needs to be a child of `self.container`, so I think this line could be rewritten as `self.row.parent.remove_widget(self.row)` which makes `self.container` unnecessary.